# Access violation when using static std::vector class member

Tags: c++, static, containers, access-violation

Every 50th or so time I got access violation in my DLL implementing UI, mostly run time is just fine, I suspect this could be due to usage of static vector:

Here is code snapshot from class methods with stack trace:

**BaseWindow.hpp**

```
#define UI_API __declspec(dllexport)

class UI_API BaseWindow
    : public Object // base class for ref counting
{
     // the rest of the code...

protected:

    /** Register window class */
    [[nodiscard]] virtual bool RegisterCls(const WNDCLASSEX& wnd_class) const;

    /** fill in window class info struct */
    [[nodiscard]] virtual bool GetClsInfo(const PCTSTR& class_name, WNDCLASSEX& wnd_class) const;

     // the rest of the code...

};
```

**BaseWindow.cpp**

```
bool BaseWindow::GetClsInfo(const PCTSTR& class_name, WNDCLASSEX& wnd_class) const
{
    if (mhInstance) // handle to HINSTANCE
    {
        if (GetClassInfoEx(mhInstance, class_name, &wnd_class))
            return true;
        else return false;  // class does not exist, not an error

    }
    else // error handling
    {
        ShowError(Exception(GenericErrorCode::InvalidHandle, TEXT("Hinstance should not be nullptr")), ERR_BOILER);
        return false;
    }
}

bool BaseWindow::RegisterCls(const WNDCLASSEX& wnd_class) const
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex{};

    // If the function does not find a matching class and successfully copy the data,
    // the return value is zero.
    if (!GetClsInfo(wnd_class.lpszClassName, wcex)) // calls above function!
    {
        // If the function fails, the return value is zero. 
        const ATOM atom = RegisterClassEx(&wnd_class);

        if (!atom) // error handling
        {
            ShowError(ERR_BOILER);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            ClassAtoms::AddClassAtom(atom); // call below function!
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**ClassAtoms.hpp**
This is where problematic static vector is declared/defined

```
#define SUPPRESS(...) __pragma(warning(suppress : __VA_ARGS__))

class UI_API ClassAtoms
{   
     // the rest of the code...

public:
    /** Add registered window class to ATOM container */
    inline static void AddClassAtom(const ATOM& atom);

    // the rest of the class

private:
    /** Container for registered window classes */
    SUPPRESS(4251);  // needs to have dll-interface (inlining will result in internal compiler error)
    static std::vector<ATOM> mAtoms;

      // the rest of the code...
};

void ClassAtoms::AddClassAtom(const ATOM& atom)
{
    mAtoms.push_back(atom);
}
```

**ClassAtoms.cpp**

```
SUPPRESS(26426);  // Global initializer calls a non-constexpr function
std::vector<ATOM> ClassAtoms::mAtoms { };
```

And here is relevant stack trace:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA691212DE (vcruntime140d.dll) in
>   TestUI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x000001A35C589000.
>
> vcruntime140d.dll!memcpy_repmovs() Line 114 Unknown
>
> > UI.dll!std::_Copy_memmove(unsigned short * _First, unsigned short * _Last, unsigned short * _Dest) Line 1745 C++
>
> UI.dll!std::_Uninitialized_move>(unsigned short * const _First, unsigned short * const _Last, unsigned short * _Dest,
>   std::allocator & _Al) Line 1738   C++
>
> UI.dll!std::vector>::_Emplace_reallocate(unsigned short *
>   const _Whereptr, const unsigned short & <_Val_0>) Line 707    C++
>
> UI.dll!std::vector>::emplace_back(const unsigned short &
>   <_Val_0>) Line 659    C++
>
> UI.dll!wsl::ui::BaseWindow::RegisterCls(const tagWNDCLASSEXW &
>   wnd_class) Line 131   C++
>
> UI.dll!wsl::ui::MainWindow::Initialize(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, int
>   x, int y, int width, int height, HWND__ * hParent, unsigned long
>   dwStyle, unsigned long dwExStyle, HICON__ * hIcon, HMENU__ * hMenu)
>   Line 68   C++
>
> TestUI.exe!TestMainWindow(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ *
>   hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 45 C++
>
> [External Code]

Do you see any problem with this code, is my vector initialized properly if so then why push_back fails?

Comment: Is `ATOM` something like a `void*`?

Comment: According to msdn: `typedef WORD ATOM` `typedef unsigned short WORD`

Comment: Yep, thank you, I found it in MSDN documentation.  ATOM is "whose value is in the range 0x0001 to 0xBFFF".

Comment: I suspect data corruption, and probably prior to the point of failure.  Do you have warnings turned on?  Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Compiling with all warnings enabled + static analyzer on max, no warnings at all (everything is resolved) except suppressed ones which are shown in the code above with `SUPPRESS` macro. the rest of the code suppresses only warnings related to `base doesn't have DLL interface` these can be ignored for standard classes according to msdn.

Comment: Just a note, If `ATOM` is just an integer, just pass it by value.

Comment: @Taekahn I already tried that, I also tried initilaizing vector with `std::shared_ptr` , and checking if shared_ptr is valid. (after some time (on every 50th or so launch)) same problem happens

Comment: I wasn't suggesting its the solution. Reference to a value type is just silly.
This is just a straight up bug: Seems to be similar to this, but its from 2018:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/251254/reading-access-violation-in-vectorpush-back.html

Comment: @Taekahn Thank you for sharing this, I will try to compile with std-c++17 instead of std-c++20-latest in VS if the solution in given answer wont work, what ever the outcome I'll report my findings here!

Comment: There's a good chance that your problem comes from something in "the rest of the code". Please make a **minimal** example by creating a copy of your code, then chop out as much as you can and still produce the error.

Comment: @Spencer thank you I will consider doing this if given comment suggestions and answers do not work. problem doing minimal sample immediately is that reproducing an error implies running a program many times, and a minimal sample code may not produce an error at all after all. I was looking for quick suggestions based on code snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a meyer's singleton:

instead of:

```
static std::vector<ATOM> mAtoms;
```

make a function:

```
static auto& atoms() {
  static std::vector<ATOM> s;
  return s;
}
```

Now the vector is initialized on first use. This also affects *static destruction order* - which may or may not be an issue - *but you should be aware of it*.

---

Alternatively you could try with an inline initialization - this can likely move the init. up in init. order.

```
 static inline std::vector<ATOM> mAtoms;
```

*and remove the .cpp init.*

---

**That being said,** it is very likely that **it is *not* that vector causing the heap corruption**.

You need to debug heap corruptions.
On windows a good start is [`_CrtSetDbgFlag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetdbgflag?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! I will implement this, and if problem does not happen again (in next few hours or until tomorrow) I'll mark this as an answer. +1 for now!

Comment: @metablaster see my update - it is probably not the vector causing corruption after all...

Comment: Thanks,I will make use of `_CrtSetDbgFlag` already reading msdn documentation!

Comment: I would like to report that this seems to be a beginners mistake! bad news is that your solution did not work but increased the frequency of crashes good news is that this helped me to quicker pinpoint the issue, and together with `CrtDebug` set of functions I determined that this was due to 2 unsynced threads accessing the vector at the same time. I don use threads at the moment, that why I didn't figure it out on my own, these 2 threads were set up only in test project, and since there were only 2 of them the crash was very rare. Thank you a lot! I learned how to debug with CRT debug fn's.